# How do I update the value of column based on other dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

How do i update a column in pandas based on condition from other data frame.
I have 2 dataframe df1 and df2

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'names':['andi','andrew','jhon','andreas'],
                 'salary':[1000,2000,2300,1500]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'names':['andi','andrew'],
                 'raise':[1500,2500]})
```

expected output

```
names    salary 
andi     1500 
andrew   2500
jhon     2300
andreas  1500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = (df2.set_index('names')['raise']
        .combine_first(df1.set_index('names')['salary'])
        .reset_index())
print (df)
     names   raise
0     andi  1500.0
1  andreas  1500.0
2   andrew  2500.0
3     jhon  2300.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using merge & update, similar like sql.

```
    df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', left_on ='names', right_on = 'names')
    df3.loc[df3['raise'].notnull(),'salary'] = df3['raise']

    df3
        names  salary   raise
    0     andi  1500.0  1500.0
    1   andrew  2500.0  2500.0
    2     jhon  2300.0     NaN
    3  andreas  1500.0     NaN
```